# How to overwrite existing core class from library?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, rxjs

I use npm library. This library contains class repository with promises methos to get data from server:

```
export class MapRepository {
 constructor(
    readonly globalEvents: MapGlobalEvent,
    baseWebApiUrl: string,
    readonly userKey: string = null
  ) {}

    getAllRegistry() {
       return this.credentialFetch(this.webApi.registry)
       .then((res) => res.ok && res.json())
       .catch(catchRequestError([]));
   }

}
```

I want to overwtire this class, thefore I am extending by apRepository. I need it to replace promises on RXJS observables using Http client.

```
export class CoreReonMapRepository extends MapRepository {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      super();// Here is problem
  }

  getAllRegistry(): Observable<any> {}
}
```

Problem is that I should pass parameters in parent constructor again, despite on `MapRepository` was loaded already in library. And I break the rule, when top modules should not depend from level modules.

How to solve that?

Somewhere in core of library:

```
 this.repository = new MapRepository(
        this.globalEvents,
        webApiUrl,
        this.props.userKey
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few options; you could require all the arguments and then forward them to the parent's constructor

```
export class CoreReonMapRepository extends MapRepository {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    readonly globalEvents: MapGlobalEvent,
    baseWebApiUrl: string,
    readonly userKey: string = null
  ) {
      super(globalEvents, baseWebApiUrl, userKey);
  }
```

Or just don't extend it, and create a decorator/proxy that implement the same interface as of MapRepository, so all you need to do if to just inject the existing instance of MapRepository to it, while the rest of your app talk to your new class

```
export class CoreReonMapRepository {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private innerMapRepository: MapRepository
  ) {}

  getAllRegistry() {
    // do other stuff
    return this.innerMapRepository.getAllRegistry()
  }
```

Comment: First approach is not suitable for me, becauese it is initialized the patent class twice. One after loading library, the second when I use this class in my app